# Usage of begin (began, begun)

Tags: verbs

Reading following sentence on the website of a Japanese company, I felt somewhat odd with the usage of "**begin**(or begun in this case)" as there are no words or phrases indicating **“timing”** in and around the sentence. I imagine you might unconsciously try to find **“when”** it began(begun), too. Is my feeling or understanding correct, or you can use “begin” without implication of “timing”?

“Not content with merely managing our forests appropriately, we **have begun** initiatives to utilize them for a range of beneficial purposes.”

Answer (score 1):

The verb "Begin" is defined by Google as "initiating the first part of an action/activity" . And it is not mandatory to mention the time. Here it implies the company has begun some initiative in just "recent past". That should be the assumption and that is what is implied too.

Answer (score 0):

My take on the word **begun** (OP's word/sentence-in-context) is that it is correct -- it sounds and looks alright to me.

The word **begun** is used here as the past participle of *begin*. I wonder if AmE uses this form? It is correct in British English; and so is the OP's word/sentence-in-context.

However, if the Japanese website edited this sentence to omit the word "have" then I believe that the word "began" may be used in place of "begun".

**Begun**: (BE) Past participle of the verb **begin**. (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Thank you. So, this sentence doesn`t odd to you despite lack of "timing", does it?

Comment: And then we have Cole Porter's song, "Begin the Beguine". But that's another story.

Comment: @comaneci My answer is based on my proficiency in speaking, reading, writing and listening to British English. I have a good working knowledge of American English. From the prospective of BE, it is correct. It is not "odd". However, it appears on a Japanese website and most Japanese with well developed English language skills tend to use AE which makes me wonder if "begun" is used in AE. Our American friends online will let us know. The "timing", which I take to mean its tense, indicates the past tense in this sentence, hence past participle of began.

Comment: Correction: "...hence past participle of BEGIN".

Comment: Dear Peter Point

Comment: Dear Peter Point. Thank you again. I actually unconsciously tried to find "when it began( started)" reading the sentence. Also, chekcing several sentences on websites of news articles, etc, "begin(began, begun) are accompanied by "timining" in many cases, so I felt my guess was correct. Of course, it goes without saying, it is depedant on context. Thank you again.